# how to join in jpql? - org.hibernate.query.SyntaxException

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Having these entities:

*User.java*:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    private String username;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Nickname> nicknames;
}
```

*Nickname.java*:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "nickname")
public class Nickname {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String value;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nickname{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", value='" + value + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and nickname repository:

```
public interface NicknameRepository extends JpaRepository<Nickname, Long> {
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
//    @Query("DELETE FROM Nickname n WHERE n.value = :value AND n.user.username = :username")
    @Query("DELETE FROM Nickname n JOIN n.user u where n.value = :value AND u.username = :username")
    void deleteNicknameByValue(@Param("username") String username, @Param("value") String value);
}
```

I am trying to join these two entities as I need `username` from `User` and `value` from `Nickname`. I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SyntaxException: At 1:23 and token 'JOIN', mismatched input 'JOIN', expecting one of the following tokens: <EOF>, WHERE [DELETE FROM Nickname n JOIN n.user u where n.value = :value AND u.username = :username]
```

whats wrong with that join?

Comment: What database are you using underlying ?

Comment: @RatulSharker mysql. Does it matter for hibernate?

Comment: Some database vendor's might not support `JOIN` in `DELETE` statement. But in this case, JPQL (the wrapper on top of vendor) itself does not support it. So the underlying database vendor does not matter.

Comment: You may be able to succeed with a subquery, e.g. `DELETE FROM Nickname n WHERE n.value = :value AND n.user = (SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username)`

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos this works, so there are at least 2 options how to perform the delete. Wondering which one to choose

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/delete)

> The structure of DELETE queries is very simple relative to the structure of SELECT queries. DELETE queries cannot include multiple variables and JOIN, and cannot include the GROUP BY, HAVING and ORDER BY clauses.

`IN` clause can be used here to delete `Nickname`s.

```java
@Query("DELETE FROM Nickname n where n.value = :value AND n.id IN (SELECT n2.id FROM Nickname n2 JOIN n2.user u WHERE u.username = :username)")
void deleteNicknameByValue(@Param("username") String username, @Param("value") String value);
```

Comment: This is somehow complicated, doing subqueries with `IN` clause. I think I will stick with `@Query("DELETE FROM Nickname n WHERE n.value = :value AND n.user.username = :username")` which hibernate translates into `EXISTS` subquery with no join and thus is more efficient

Comment: moreover this gives another error:

`org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: JDBC exception executing SQL [delete from nickname where value=? and id in (select n2_0.id from nickname n2_0 join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=n2_0.user_id where u1_0.username=?)] [You can't specify target table 'nickname' for update in FROM clause] [n/a]`